# PHP socket not working on windows 2012

Tags: php, sockets, windows-server-2012, windows-server-2012-r2, php-socket

I have PHP socket server working on one server. I have replicate the code and put it on another server(Windows server 2012 r2). I have changed few things e.g. localhost ip and port. when I run the file through cmd it doesn't do any thing.

here is the code.

```
$address=gethostbyname('localhost');
$port = 99999;
echo $address;
echo 'Hello';
if (($sock = socket_create(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, SOL_TCP)) === false) {
    echo "socket_create() failed: reason: " . socket_strerror(socket_last_error()) . "\n";
}
echo 'Hello2';
if (socket_bind($sock, $address, $port) === false) {
    echo "socket_bind() failed: reason: " . socket_strerror(socket_last_error($sock)) . "\n";
}
echo 'Hello3';
if (socket_listen($sock, 5) === false) {
    echo "socket_listen() failed: reason: " . socket_strerror(socket_last_error($sock)) . "\n";
}
```

Here is the out put I get. I have not disabled any error reporting either.

[image]

As you can see its just 'echoing' first hello and then just shows the new line.

So any idea why it is doing it?

p.s. php_sockets.dll is enabled. I have tried changing ip to ipv6 and some other ports but on luck.

Many Thanks in advace.

Comment: `$port = 99999;` - port number is a two-byte value, so 65535 is maximum. Though it's possibly not the root cause of your issue.

Comment: I tried changing it to 4999 etc. but it isnt the issue.